# Saving all Weapon ID Numbers with loop

Tags: c#, linq, loops, unity-game-engine, foreach

I have no programming background and i am playing around with Unity Engine.
So i have a Item Manager. All Weapons have ID Numbers like 23 for Axe, 9 for Handgung etc...

I am trying to make a save load system.

```
public void save() {
    var itemManager = gameObject.GetComponent<vItemManager>();
        if (itemManager != null) {
            foreach(var weapon1 in itemManager.items) {
                // Shows all Weapon Id numbers that is equipped (in the console)
                Debug.Log(weapon1.id); 
                /*
                It just saves the id of the last weapon equipped other weapons ids are
                missing....(the id of the last weapon was saved into registry i want to save all weapon ids into registry..)

                Playerprefs: Stores and accesses player preferences between game
                sessions.

                SetInt: Sets the value of the preference identified by key.
                */
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("nummer", weapon1.id); 
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use unique key for saving. But you are using the same key for all ids: "nummer".

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var weapon1 in itemManager.items) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("nummer_" + i++, weapon1.id); 
}
```

But there is a question: How do you gonna read from PlayerPrefs unknown keys?
Better way is serialize your weapons list into file.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html
https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/serialization-and-game-data

Or you can combine all your ids into string, save them to the PlayerPrefs and parse when read:

```
//save
String weaponsList;
foreach(var weapon1 in itemManager.items) {
    weaponsList += weapon1.id + ',';
}
PlayerPrefs.SetString ("weapons",weaponsList); 

//load
String weaponsList = PlayerPrefs.GetString("weapons", String.Empty);
var weaponsIds= weaponsList.Split(new[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var weaponId in weaponsIds) {
   //...
}
```